# Why am I not getting the correct inverse Laplace transform?

Tags: calculus, inverse-laplace

$$ {(s^2 -3)} \over (s+2)(s-3)(s^2+2s+5)$$

I was trying to get the correct result of this inverse of Laplace but I still get the wrong result because I get these results as coefficients:

$$A = \frac 15$$
$$B = 0$$
$$C = -\frac15$$
$$D = 1$$
But applying the inverse of Laplace does not agree with what it says in the book as the result, which is the following:

$$\frac 3{50}e^{3t} -\frac 1{25}e^{-2t}- \frac 1{50}e^{-t}\cos(2t) +\frac9{25}e^t \sec(2t)$$

Comment: You calculated the coefficients incorrectly. Recheck your work with the partial fractions and compare with the result computed by [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+(s%5E2+-3)%2F%5B(s%2B2)(s-3)(s%5E2%2B2s%2B5)%5D)

Comment: Yes but somehow I got different partial fractions because I did :

Comment: A/s+2 +B/(s-3)+ Cs+D/(s^2+2s+5)...

Comment: thank you  :D !  gonna calculate again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your coefficients are not correct.

There are different methods to find the coefficient.

Use a different method and make sure that you do not make any arithmetic error.

You may find coefficients of $1/(s-3)$ and $ 1/(s+2)$ by Heaviside's method and subtract the result from the left side to find the other two coefficients.

Comment: Thank you  Mohammad :) Heaviside's method is a great  idea

Comment: Thanks for attention. Good luck with your calculations.